Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{F(x)}{x\sqrt{x}}$, where $F(x) = \int_0^{x^2} \left( e^{-t^2} - e^{-1} \right)dt$, without L'hopital

Take the function
$$F(x) =  \int_0^{x^2} \left( e^{-t^2} - e^{-1} \right)dt $$
I need to find
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{F(x)}{x\sqrt{x}}$$

I thought I could use Mean Value Theorem for Integrals. Then
$$ \int_0^{x^2} e^{-t^2} - e^{-1}dt = \left(e^{-c^2} - e^{-1}\right)x^2$$ for some $\ c \in (0,x^2)$. Then the limit goes to zero. I used L’Hopital and the result is zero too (perhaps is just a coincidence)
But I have a intuition that my solution is wrong. I have seen posts on this forum with similar questions, and none of the answers use Mean Value Theorem for integrals.
Can someone help me with this? Is my solution correct or not? Is there other way of solving this (without L’Hopital)?
Thanks.
EDIT : For example in this post : How to calculate this limit involving an integral
When I used Mean Value Integrals for Integrals, the result of the limit is infinity, but the actual result $\frac{1}{3}$
What is the difference between both cases?

Your solution is correct (although $c$ depends on $x$ and so you should argue why $\sqrt{x}(e^{-c(x)^2}-e^{-1})\to 0$).

As $t\to 0^+$, $(e^{-t^2}-e^{-1})\sim (1-1/e)$ and then you have $\frac1{x^{3/2}}{\int_0^{x^2} k dt} \to 0$ where $k=1-1/e$

@JulioPuerta Thanks. I added an edit in which I expand the topic

@SineoftheTime Thanks, I made an edit with an extra question.

Change variable $y=x\sqrt{x}$. Then $\lim_{y\to 0}F(y)/y=F'(y)$. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus

Observe that  for $x\le 1 $ and $t\le x$ we have $0\le e^{-t^2}-e^{-1}\le 1.$  Thus $0\le F(x)x^{-3/2}\le x^2x^{-3/2}=x^{1/2}.$

Let $f(x) = \int_0^x (e^{-t^2} -\frac{1}{e})dt$.  Then
$$
\frac{F(x)}{x\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x}\,\frac{f(x^2)}{x^2}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x^2)}{x^2}
= \lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{f(y)}{y}
= e^{-y^2}|_{y=0} -\frac{1}{e}
= 1 -\frac{1}{e}.
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{F(x)}{x\sqrt{x}}
= \lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{x} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x^2)}{x^2}
= 0.
$$
